# Connected to 1080p TV, Scaling on laptop wrong

Tags: resolution, hdmi

im using a Lenovo Thinkpad edge 13, Turion neo x2 L625 1.6ghz, 2gb 5300 ram.

I wanted to try connecting it to my LG 42" lcd tv, everything worked good, mouse was sliding between screens and everything, but after i took a Restart of the computer, suddenly the text scaling and everything on my laptop was messed up,
Actually looked like it was using the scaling of my 1080p TV..

I have tried going back and forth on scaling settings but nothing worked..

I belive the problem hails from the screen setting section, do i have to reinstall ubuntu to get it right?

Laptop resolution: 1366 x 768

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com  Please help us help you by editing your question and adding the content of /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the laptop is mirroring the TV's display. One solution could be is to open up the display settings in Ubuntu's settings and uncheck the mirror displays. Then disconnect, reboot if necessary (I.e. if there is no perceivable change)  and connect the HDMI cord again.